# Can publisher actions be made available on a VisualForce Page?

Tags: visualforce, publisher-action

I have created a mobile responsive Visual Force page for a custom object.
I need the publisher action associated with that custom object to appear on my Visual Force Page.

How Can i accomplish this?

Comment: To split hairs a bit, do you mean you want the control to invoke the publisher action to appear?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SF.SE user12128. There are two types of Publisher Actions of the type you speak of, Global Actions and Object Specific Actions. The latter can only appear on Detail Pages. Global Actions can appear anywhere, including on Detail Pages. They're both discussed in depth, including how to enable them in Chapter 8 of the [Force.com Platform Fundamentals Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf).